# Compute the risk measured by the standard deviations $\sigma K_1, \sigma K_2, \sigma K_3$, does this have to do with weights?

Tags: finance, returns, standard-deviation, financial-engineering, finance-mathematics

Compute the risk measured by the standard deviations $\sigma K_1, \sigma K_2, \sigma K_3$ for each of the investment projects, where the returns $K_1, K_2$, and $K_3$ depend on the market scenario:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        Scenario & Probability & Return K_1 & Return K_2 & Return K_3 \\
        \omega_1 & 0.3 & 12\% & 11\% & 2\% \\
        \omega_2 & 0.7 & 12\% & 15\% & 22\% \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

I am not sure what this question is asking me to do, I think it has something to do with weights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very basic question. You just need to compute the standard deviation of three projects $K_1$, $K_2$ and $K_3$.

## $$\text{Standard deviation}= \sqrt{E[(X-\mu)^2]}$$

## For the first project $K_1$:

Expected return ($\mu_{K_1}$) =  $.3*.12 + .7*.12 = .12$

Standard Deviation ($\sigma K_1$) = $\sqrt{.3*(.12-.12)^2+.7*(.12-.12)^2}=0
$

## For the second project $K_2$:

Expected return ($\mu_{K_2}$) =  $.3*.11 + .7*.15 = .138$

Standard Deviation ($\sigma K_1$) = $\sqrt{.3*(.11-.138)^2+.7*(.15-.138)^2}=0.018330=1.83\% $

## You may follow the same procedure for the third project.